# Неправильный аргумент в функции open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске вот этой команды:

```
f=open(r"F:\file.txt","w")
f.write("Hello,world")
f.close()
```

Вместо `F:\` можно поставить любой другой диск (не путь) всё равно будет эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gleb/PycharmProjects/OpenPr/dir1/asd.py", line 1, in <module>
    f=open(r"F:\file.txt","w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\file.txt'
```

А если вводить путь, допустим, `F:\dir\file.txt`, то всё работает.
Права на создание файлов есть, но при обычном запуске та же ошибка, а при запуске через админа все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: у вас есть права писать в корень диска `F:`?

Comment: У меня работает. Вот с правами действительно может быть запрет на доступ.

Comment: @MaxU Права есть, сейчас в вопрос скрины выложу. Но попробовал запустить через админа все вышло

Comment: Что происходит если попробовать: `f=open(r"F:/file.txt","w")` ?

Comment: Значит,  прав нет у питона.

Comment: @MaxU тоже самое

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka А как дать?

Comment: Через админа все время запускайте

Comment: Вообще как правило не нужно "ломать систему" и пытаться записать в корень диска (или в папки Windows или Program Files, например) и что-либо. Если сильно нужно - тогда проще действительно запускать программу от админа. Смысл в том, что запуск админа - это действие только для вашей программы, а изменение прав доступа дает возможность любой программе писать в корень диска, или туда куда вы еще захотите дать полные права доступа.